# TFS Error: Source Control Explorer - Unable to read data from transport connection

Tags: tfs

When I try to get latest version of project in TFS it does not work and produces this error:

'Source Control Explorer. Unable to read data from transport connection. The connection was closed.' How do I fix this so I can get the latest version of the project's code?

Comment: What's your environment of tfs and the server holding TFS? Did you get any related error info in event view on the TFS  server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According  the error message seems like the connection to the server was made but since the service was not available on machine, then the sever canceled the request.

You could try below ways to narrow down the issue:

- First check the **event view** on the TFS server if there are some
  related error info.
- Try to get another team project in some collection and different team
  project collection.
- Try to use another account to get latest on your machine.
- Try to use your account to get latest on another machine. If the
  issue only occurs on your machine, you may need to [clear TFS and VS
  cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) which may do the trick.
- If you are using Window Server 2008R2. Maybe it's related [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2010/02/10/team-foundation-server-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/)
  issue. Applied the [HotFix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981898/a-file-does-not-download-from-an-iis-7.5-server-that-is-running-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2) and try the workaround.

Comment: Trying to retrieve the entire solution never did work for me, but I then was able to retrieve each folder individually (which retrieved all files and files in subfolders) in the solution. So, I'm thinking that it was failing because there were too many files to get at one time. Now, if I get latest version on the solution it works since all files have been downloaded.